# Devise Mailer uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I did all like in this tutorial:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer
On production everything works fine but on development env i get

NameError (uninitialized constant MyMailer):

```
bootsnap (1.3.1) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:53:in `block in load_missing_constant'
bootsnap (1.3.1) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
bootsnap (1.3.1) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:53:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
bootsnap (1.3.1) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:42:in `load_missing_constant'
```

in devise initializer i have
`config.mailer = "MyMailer"'`

it seems like it got change only for production.

**Update**
so its about this

`config.eager_load = false` in development env

when set to `true`, everything works fine like in production.

So what is a workaround ? Im not sure if I should set it that way.

*mailers/mymailer.rb*

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer   
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views
  include DefaultUrlOptions
end
```

Comment: did you restart your server ?

Comment: Yes, I found solution I will post update in sec

Comment: Where did you place the `my_mailer.rb` file?

Comment: in mailers/mymailer.rb, so it should be my_mailer.rb... ,no.. mymailer_mailer.rb ?

Comment: it has to be mailers/my_mailer.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In development mode Rails tries to find (autoload) the class definition by its name. Make sure the `MyMailer` class is defined in a file named `my_mailer.rb` and placed in one of directories that are searched by Rails when class autoloading, such as `mailers`, `models`, `services`.

Comment: but why it works on production ? eager_loads anything what finds ?

Comment: Yes, loads everything from `Rails.application.config.eager_load_paths`

Comment: ok, so it loads everything on production at the beginning, while on dev it needs to reaload each time only the file that it needs and then it needs only "my_mailer"